# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении? (1)

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "войну"? Почему?

*Прячась в окопе войну не выиграть.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, запятая нужна.

"Прячась в окопе" - деепричастный оборот, он указывает на наличие дополнительного действия того же лица и отвечает на вопрос "что делая?". Деепричастный оборот выполняет роль обстоятельства и выделяется запятыми.

*Прячась в окопе, войну не выиграть.*

Comment: Возникает вопрос, что же это за то же лицо.))